# R comparison of two lists

Tags: r, list

I have two lists that I want to compare by extracting the exact positions of items in list1 that are also in list 2.

```
a <- c(8, 28, 23, 21)
b <- c(28, 27, 8, 7)
```

I have tried %in% or intersect but I can't figure out how to get the index of shared items.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: could you post an example of the two lists and the intended output?

Comment: a<-c(8, 28, 23, 21 )
b<-c(28, 27, 8, 7), output should be: 8 -> position 3 , 28 -> position 1

Comment: are you looking for `which(a %in% b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned a list, but have posted two integer vectors.

As a more general case to `%in%` you can use `match`. Here is an example based on some sample data.

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
lst <- list(
    one = sample(10),
    two = sample(10));
lst;
#$one
# [1] 10  5  4  3  9  8  1  2  6  7
#
#$two
# [1]  7  1  9  4  3  2  5  6 10  8

# Index of lst$one elements in lst$two. 
idx_one_in_two <- match(lst[[1]], lst[[2]]);
idx_one_in_two;
# [1]  9  7  4  5  3 10  2  6  8  1
```

For example, element 1 in `lst$one` (`lst$one[1] = 7`) is located at position `9` in `lst$two`.

Similarly, for elements `lst$two` in `lst$one`.

```
# Index of lst$two elements in lst$one. 
idx_two_in_one <- match(lst[[2]], lst[[1]]);
# [1] 10  7  5  3  4  8  2  9  1  6
```

---

### Update

Based on your sample data, you can do the following:

```
a <- c(8, 28, 23, 21)
b <- c(28, 27, 8, 7)

# Index of a in b
match(a, b);
#[1]  3  1 NA NA

# Index of b in a
match(b, a);
#[1]  2 NA  1 NA
```